# Issues with Stepwise Automated Linear Regression Search Procedure using F-Statistics

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression, statsmodels

I am trying to run a stepwise automated search procedure on Python with linear regression, with my code shown below, using code from https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/24447 I did not change any of the code given by the contributor, but am still encountering errors:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm

data = load_boston()
X = pd.DataFrame(data.data, columns=data.feature_names)
y = data.target


def stepwise_selection(X, y, 
                       initial_list=[], 
                       threshold_in=0.01, 
                       threshold_out = 0.05, 
                       verbose=True):
    """ Perform a forward-backward feature selection 
    based on p-value from statsmodels.api.OLS
    Arguments:
        X - pandas.DataFrame with candidate features
        y - list-like with the target
        initial_list - list of features to start with (column names of X)
        threshold_in - include a feature if its p-value < threshold_in
        threshold_out - exclude a feature if its p-value > threshold_out
        verbose - whether to print the sequence of inclusions and exclusions
    Returns: list of selected features 
    Always set threshold_in < threshold_out to avoid infinite looping.
    See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stepwise_regression for the details
    """
    included = list(initial_list)
    while True:
        changed=False
        # forward step
        excluded = list(set(X.columns)-set(included))
        new_pval = pd.Series(index=excluded)
        for new_column in excluded:
            model = sm.OLS(y, sm.add_constant(pd.DataFrame(X[included+[new_column]]))).fit()
            new_pval[new_column] = model.pvalues[new_column]
        best_pval = new_pval.min()
        if best_pval < threshold_in:
            best_feature = new_pval.argmin()
            included.append(best_feature)
            changed=True
            if verbose:
                print('Add  {:30} with p-value {:.6}'.format(best_feature, best_pval))

        # backward step
        model = sm.OLS(y, sm.add_constant(pd.DataFrame(X[included]))).fit()
        # use all coefs except intercept
        pvalues = model.pvalues.iloc[1:]
        worst_pval = pvalues.max() # null if pvalues is empty
        if worst_pval > threshold_out:
            changed=True
            worst_feature = pvalues.argmax()
            included.remove(worst_feature)
            if verbose:
                print('Drop {:30} with p-value {:.6}'.format(worst_feature, worst_pval))
        if not changed:
            break
    return included

result = stepwise_selection(X, y)

print('resulting features:')
print(result)
```

However, I have run into the following error:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-782c721f1ba0> in <module>
     59     return included
     60 
---> 61 result = stepwise_selection(X, y)
     62 
     63 print('resulting features:')

<ipython-input-21-782c721f1ba0> in stepwise_selection(X, y, initial_list, threshold_in, threshold_out, verbose)
     45 
     46         # backward step
---> 47         model = sm.OLS(y, sm.add_constant(pd.DataFrame(X[included]))).fit()
     48         # use all coefs except intercept
     49         pvalues = model.pvalues.iloc[1:]

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2804             if is_iterator(key):
   2805                 key = list(key)
-> 2806             indexer = self.loc._get_listlike_indexer(key, axis=1, raise_missing=True)[1]
   2807 
   2808         # take() does not accept boolean indexers

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _get_listlike_indexer(self, key, axis, raise_missing)
   1551 
   1552         self._validate_read_indexer(
-> 1553             keyarr, indexer, o._get_axis_number(axis), raise_missing=raise_missing
   1554         )
   1555         return keyarr, indexer

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _validate_read_indexer(self, key, indexer, axis, raise_missing)
   1638             if missing == len(indexer):
   1639                 axis_name = self.obj._get_axis_name(axis)
-> 1640                 raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")
   1641 
   1642             # We (temporarily) allow for some missing keys with .loc, except in

KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([8], dtype='int64')] are in the [columns]"
```

Expected output should be this:

```
Add  LSTAT                          with p-value 5.0811e-88
Add  RM                             with p-value 3.47226e-27
Add  PTRATIO                        with p-value 1.64466e-14
Add  DIS                            with p-value 1.66847e-05
Add  NOX                            with p-value 5.48815e-08
Add  CHAS                           with p-value 0.000265473
Add  B                              with p-value 0.000771946
Add  ZN                             with p-value 0.00465162
resulting features:
['LSTAT', 'RM', 'PTRATIO', 'DIS', 'NOX', 'CHAS', 'B', 'ZN']
```

Appreciate any help given, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how the code actually worked in the first place, maybe argmax worked differently. You get the error because of this line:

```
best_feature = new_pval.argmin()
```

You need the actual name of the feature, so if you change it to:

```
new_pval[new_column] = model.pvalues[new_column]
```

And likewise this line:

```
worst_feature = pvalues.argmax()
```

To:

```
worst_feature = new_pval.index[pvalues.argmax()]
```

I get this:

```
Add  LSTAT                          with p-value 5.0811e-88
Add  RM                             with p-value 3.47226e-27
Add  PTRATIO                        with p-value 1.64466e-14
Add  DIS                            with p-value 1.66847e-05
Add  NOX                            with p-value 5.48815e-08
Add  CHAS                           with p-value 0.000265473
Add  B                              with p-value 0.000771946
Add  ZN                             with p-value 0.00465162
resulting features:
['LSTAT', 'RM', 'PTRATIO', 'DIS', 'NOX', 'CHAS', 'B', 'ZN']
```

Although here, from a statistical point of view, I have some doubts about the implementation. I suggest you maybe post this in cross-validated or as another question.